# How to configure Android Service?

Tags: android, android-service

I Have a android service running. When i go to Settings-Applications-running Services- XYZ Service and click on XYZ Service, it asks me to Stop Service with Stop and Cancel button. Here I Want to have some options on click of XYZ Service. Please let me know the way how to do this? Thanks

Comment: options to do what? If you want to configure the service, you will have to create an Activity for the user to interact with and have it inform the service of the changes.

Comment: Yes Chris, I want to configure the service.

Comment: You can't add buttons to that screen. You can create an activity that writes settings to a SharedPreferences and read it from the service. Search Android SDK docs, there are tons of examples.